# C# ASP.Net Image attribute with javascript onclick not working in IE9

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I'm using a Datalist to populate a vehicle with its images as thumbnails.
When a user clicks on a small image, the onclick event needs to recall the image from the database and load it into an above bigger Image control.
I'm using an ImageHandler.ashx, to retrieve the image binary from SQL and renders it in the image control.

Everything works perfect in Chrome and IE7, but not working in IE9.
If I click on the small image in IE9, its like the image handler never executes, the bigger image never gets loaded with the selected image. When viewing page source in IE9, the code looks as follows:

IE9 Page source:

```
<table id="table1" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; width: 108px; height: 73px;
        background-image: url('Images/smallimageframe.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <img id="DataListVehicles_ctl00_imgVehicle" class="imgOpacity" onerror="this.src='Images/no_image.jpg'" onclick="imgBig.src='ImageHandler.ashx?ID=29';" src="ImageHandler.ashx?ID=29" alt="29" style="border-style:None;height:55px;width:90px;border-width:0px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td><td class="DataList">
    <table id="table1" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; width: 108px; height: 73px;
        background-image: url('Images/smallimageframe.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <img id="DataListVehicles_ctl01_imgVehicle" class="imgOpacity" onerror="this.src='Images/no_image.jpg'" onclick="imgBig.src='ImageHandler.ashx?ID=30';" src="ImageHandler.ashx?ID=30" alt="30" style="border-style:None;height:55px;width:90px;border-width:0px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td><td class="DataList">
    <table id="table1" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; width: 108px; height: 73px;
        background-image: url('Images/smallimageframe.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <img id="DataListVehicles_ctl02_imgVehicle" class="imgOpacity" onerror="this.src='Images/no_image.jpg'" onclick="imgBig.src='ImageHandler.ashx?ID=31';" src="ImageHandler.ashx?ID=31" alt="31" style="border-style:None;height:55px;width:90px;border-width:0px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Server side:

```
    protected void DataListVehicles_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Image imgVehicle = e.Item.FindControl("imgVehicle") as Image;               
            imgVehicle.ImageUrl = "ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + m_Vehicles.ListingPhotos[e.Item.ItemIndex].ID;

            imgVehicle.Attributes.Add("onclick", "imgBig.src='ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + m_Vehicles.ListingPhotos[e.Item.ItemIndex].ID + "';"); 
        }
    }
```

Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <link href="css/asp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('.imgOpacity').each(function() {
                $(this).hover(
                    function() {
                        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
                    },
                   function() {
                       $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 500);
                   })
            });
        });
    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table style="width: 780px" class="OtherControl">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-left: 8px; padding-top: 3px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF9900"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <table style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; width: 320px; height: 220px; background-image: url('Images/imageframe.png');
                                    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <asp:Image ID="imgBig" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="300px" onerror="this.src='Images/no_image.jpg'"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <asp:DataList ID="DataListVehicles" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="4"
                                    ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" BorderStyle="None" OnItemDataBound="DataListVehicles_ItemDataBound"
                                    HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemStyle CssClass="DataList" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <table id="table1" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0px; width: 108px; height: 73px;
                                            background-image: url('Images/smallimageframe.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                    <asp:Image ID="imgVehicle" runat="server" CssClass="imgOpacity" Width="90px" Height="55px"
                                                        onerror="this.src='Images/no_image.jpg'" BorderStyle="None" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:DataList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>            
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the way you are referring to "imgBig" from the onClick JavaScript, you could try using document.getElementById('imgBig').src='.... instead.  Also have you opened the IE developer tools window and checked for JavaScript errors when you click the image?

Comment: I'll give that a try thank you.
The IE developer tools gives the following error onclick:

            SCRIPT5009: 'imgBig' is undefined.

Hopefully your change will fix this, will get back to you shortly.

Comment: Your original code was assuming a variable 'imgBig' is defined in scope, which depending on the browser won't always be the case. Alternatively, as you are already using JQuery, you could do `$('#imgBig').attr('src')='...` which should work cross-browser as well.  Finally for completeness in your sever side code you should do `"$('#" + imgBig.ClientID + "').attr('src')=...` to get the client side id generated for imgBig.  This won't make any difference in your case, however had imgBig been inside a panel or some other control the client id might end up decorated by ASP.NET.

Comment: Just thought I'd share this for anyone else that might need it.
`document.getElementById` worked fine, until I implemented master pages into my project. Then I got the error
"unable to set value of the property 'src' object is null or undefined"
So, changing my code again, this time to the JQuery tip as stated by LambyPie.
`imgVehicle.Attributes.Add("onclick", "$('#" + imgBig.ClientID + "').attr({src:'ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + m_Vehicles.ListingPhotos[e.Item.ItemIndex].ID + "'});");`

It works great again :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
imgVehicle.Attributes.Add("onclick", "imgBig.src='ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + m_Vehicles.ListingPhotos[e.Item.ItemIndex].ID + "';");
```

Try this

```
imgVehicle.Attributes.Add("onclick", imgBig.ClientID + ".src='ImageHandler.ashx?ID=" + m_Vehicles.ListingPhotos[e.Item.ItemIndex].ID + "';");
```

in `DataListVehicles_ItemDataBound`

Comment: Id like to refer to the "imgBig" image though, Wouldn't 'this' just be reassigned to its existing image?

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, the rendered page in IE still only returned 'imgBig' as the clientID. Thanks for your help though!